# Create copy of file in my Drive and place in another user's Drive on the same domain

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

How do I make it so when an employee runs the script to create copies of the file and distribute them to other folders, it can also place them in folders on other employees' Drives? We are on the same domain and use G Suite.

My script is for a timesheet. It is supposed to:

1. create a copy, append the name with the userid and timestamp, and then place the copy in a folder on the employee's Drive so they have a copy,
2. repeat this and place the second copy in a folder on my Drive so I have a copy without the employee having to share it, and so the employee cannot later edit my copy

It worked well when I was testing it myself. Then, I shared it with a colleague on the same domain, and with my personal Google account. We both created a copy on our Drives (his work Drive, my personal Drive). Then, we were no longer working from the original. This is intentional because I don't want employees touching the original. When we ran the script, it failed to create a copy on our Drives or my work Drive.

"Exception: No item with the given ID could be found, or you do not have permission to access it."

here is my code so far:

```
function submit() {
  //variables
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var destFolderMgr = DriveApp.getFolderById(my folder id is here);
  var destFolderEmp = DriveApp.getFolder;
  var empName = Session.getActiveUser()
  var timeStamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), 'MM-dd-yyyy');
  var newName = ss.getName() + " " + empName + " " + timeStamp;

  //copy sheet
  //append name with today's date and employee name
  //place in employee's folder
  DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).makeCopy(newName,destFolderEmp)

  //copy sheet
  //append name with today's date and employee name
  //place in manager's folder
  DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).makeCopy(newName,destFolderMgr)

}
```

Comment: Did you have permission to access their drive?

Comment: I don't know. I imagine I could get that done with full admin privileges on G Suite. But, I don't believe I would want them to have permission to access my Drive, and that is the direction I need these files to travel. From their Drive to mine. Is it possible to give the employees access to my Drive only for this purpose, without them being able to actually open it and peruse my files?

Comment: Have you though about using a shared drive?

Comment: I haven't. I'll look into that, thx. So long as each employee's file (timesheet) is not accessible or viewable by other employees.

Comment: Well that's not going to work then.

Comment: Personally, I'd do it with a web app.  Deploy it to execute as you and don't give them any access to your drive or files.  But that's just me.

Comment: LOL. Personally, I'd buy a cloud based HR service. But, I'll look into web apps. I just discovered app script this week. Currently, everyone's timesheet is saved to their work Drive and they share the folder with me. It works, but is a lot of work for me to go to each folder, pull the file, copy the contents, and then save the file as pdf on my Drive so I have an unalterable copy preserved. Oh, and there's always that one employee who doesn't "make a copy" but instead directly edits the original template each pay period. Yay.

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue:

You want your employees to be able to insert files to your Drive without having permission to even view your Drive. This is not possible.

#### Workaround:

As Cooper said, a good way to circumvent this problem is to deploy your application as a web app, and, when deploying it, set "**Execute the app as**" to you. This way, even if it's other users accessing this web app, the web app executes as you, and can access the same resources as you.

I think the simplest way to do this would be to name your function `doGet`. This specially named function runs [every time someone makes a `GET` request](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html#serve_html_as_a_web_app) to the web app URL (that is to say, every time someone accesses this URL). This way, every time someone accesses this URL, a copy of the file is made to the two specified folders.

Now, I don't know how the employee folder ID is retrieved, depending on which user is running the script, but in the function itself you could declare an object containing key-value pairs with the different employee mails and the corresponding folder ID's.

Finally, you could return some [HtmlOutput](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output) at the end of this function to inform users that the process was completed succesfully (instead of showing an error for not returning anything).

It could be something like this:

#### Code sample:

```js
function doGet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var empName = Session.getActiveUser();
  var employeeFolders = { // Employee emails and folder ID's
    emailEmployee1: "folder-id-1",
    emailEmployee2: "folder-id-2",
    emailEmployee3: "folder-id-3",
    //...
  }
  var empFolderId = employeeFolders[empName];
  var destFolderEmp = DriveApp.getFolderById(empFolderId);
  var destFolderMgr = DriveApp.getFolderById(my folder id is here);
  var timeStamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), 'MM-dd-yyyy');
  var newName = ss.getName() + " " + empName + " " + timeStamp;
  DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).makeCopy(newName,destFolderEmp)
  DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).makeCopy(newName,destFolderMgr)
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("Copy made!");
}
```

Once you have copied this code your project, you can deploy the script as a web app if you follow [these steps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploying_a_script_as_a_web_app).

#### Note:

- You should have access to the employees folders for this to work.
- This is the simplest way to do this, but many details could be added (serving HTML pages and making users clicking a button to run the script, etc.). I'd suggest you to read the Web Apps link I included in reference if you want to investigate further.

#### Reference:

- [Apps Script: Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)